# Go - Inconsistent Evaluation of Deferred Functions

Tags: go, deferred-execution

I am experimenting with Go and am seeing some unexpected behaviour with deferred functions.  Consider the following program that increments a global variable by a given amount.

```
package main

import "fmt"

var z = 1

func main() {

    defer increaseZ(10)
    defer fmt.Println("z =", increaseZ(20), "Deferred Value 1")
    defer fmt.Println("z =", increaseZ(30), "Deferred Value 2")

    fmt.Println("z =", z, "Main Value")
}

func increaseZ(y int) int {
    z += y
    println("z =", z, "Inside Increase Function")
    return z
}
```

When [run in the go playground](http://play.golang.org/p/6yi3bJ83K2), this outputs:

```
z = 21 Inside Increase Function
z = 51 Inside Increase Function
z = 61 Inside Increase Function
z = 51 Main Value
z = 51 Deferred Value 2
z = 21 Deferred Value 1
```

If I switch the order of the deferred functions, it has another effect:

```
defer fmt.Println("z =", increaseZ(20), "Deferred Value 1")
defer fmt.Println("z =", increaseZ(30), "Deferred Value 2")
defer increaseZ(10)
```

Outputs:

```
z = 21 Inside Increase Function
z = 51 Inside Increase Function
z = 51 Main Value
z = 61 Inside Increase Function
z = 51 Deferred Value 2
z = 21 Deferred Value 1
```

The Go documentation states:

> The deferred call's arguments are evaluated immediately, but the
>   function call is not executed until the surrounding function returns.

So *arguments being evaluated*, may explain why the Main Value returned is 51 and not 61, since the fmt.Println statements are taking `increaseZ` as an argument, but `defer increaseZ(10)` would not be called until after the main function returns.

However, this does not explain why in the first example the `increaseZ(10)` is outputting before main has completed, and after main has completed in the second example.

I would be grateful if anyone could help me understand what is happening here, since this looks like fertile ground for difficult to diagnose bugs further down the line.

Comment: This is interesting.

Comment: Don't use [`println`. From the docs:](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#println) "[…] in an implementation- specific way […] it is not guaranteed to stay in the language."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are being inconsistent in your print destination.

```
stdout: fmt.Println

stderr: println
```

Write to the same print destination.

```
package main

import "fmt"

var z = 1

func main() {

    defer increaseZ(10)
    defer fmt.Println("z =", increaseZ(20), "Deferred Value 1")
    defer fmt.Println("z =", increaseZ(30), "Deferred Value 2")

    fmt.Println("z =", z, "Main Value")
}

func increaseZ(y int) int {
    z += y
    fmt.Println("z =", z, "Inside Increase Function")
    return z
}
```

Output:

```
z = 21 Inside Increase Function
z = 51 Inside Increase Function
z = 51 Main Value
z = 51 Deferred Value 2
z = 21 Deferred Value 1
z = 61 Inside Increase Function
```

or,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

var z = 1

func main() {

    defer increaseZ(10)
    defer fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "z =", increaseZ(20), "Deferred Value 1")
    defer fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "z =", increaseZ(30), "Deferred Value 2")

    fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "z =", z, "Main Value")
}

func increaseZ(y int) int {
    z += y
    println("z =", z, "Inside Increase Function")
    return z
}
```

Output:

```
z = 21 Inside Increase Function
z = 51 Inside Increase Function
z = 51 Main Value
z = 51 Deferred Value 2
z = 21 Deferred Value 1
z = 61 Inside Increase Function
```

Comment: `println` writing to `stderr` explains things perfectly.  Could you share where this is documented?

Comment: @PassKit: In the Go [builtin](http://golang.org/pkg/builtin/) pseudo package documentation. [`func println`](http://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#println): The `println` built-in function formats its arguments in an implementation-specific way and writes the result to standard error.

Answer (score 2):

It's not about deferred evaluations. It's about printing. `println` function documented for completeness but are not guaranteed to stay in the language at all. Also Stdout and Stderr merged in one stream on Playground by design.
If you use `fmt.Println(...)` everywhere http://play.golang.org/p/PU3hxHCazA
or explicitly define  `fmt.Fprintln(os.Stdout, ...` http://play.golang.org/p/OQpOQR2vm0 things would work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is a bug with the Go playground. When I compile and run this program on my machine, it yields the expected output. A [bug report](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/10279) pertaining this issue has been filed.

Comment: Validated, it runs as expected when compiled on `go1.4.2 darwin/amd64`

Comment: NOTE: The [Go bug report](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/10279) has been rejected as invalid. There is no Go bug. The behavior is as expected. The bug is in the program. See my answer for details.

Comment: It hasn't been rejected, I closed it. What is weird is that I wasn't able to reproduce this behaviour by any other means.